# Do we have to mention exception type in java?

Tags: java, exception

I just found

```
try  
{ 
    Thread.sleep(50); 
} catch(Exception ex){  }
```

works just fine. Then why do we need to explicitly mention the exception type?

```
try  
{ 
    Thread.sleep(50); 
} catch(InterruptedException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Because if that code changes, you may be catching exceptions that you don't actually know how to handle properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we explicitly mention exception type?

To control *which* exceptions we catch. Exceptions which aren't of the defined class (or a subclass of it) will propagate to the caller. So for instance, I can say I'm going to handle an `IOException` in my code, but if a `FooBarException` occurs, I'll leave it for the caller to handle.

I recommend reading through the [Java exceptions tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 0):

A `catch` clause will commence if the given type of exception is thrown, **or any of its subclasses**. `Exception` isn't a special keyword - it's a name of a class - `java.lang.Exception`, from which all checked exceptions inherit. If you want to catch **any** exception, including unchecked exceptions, you could use `catch (Throwable t)`. Although note this is rarely a good idea.

Comment: RuntimeException extends Exception. You need Throwable to catch Error and its subclasses, as well as Exception.